# Simple Recaptcha in PHP?

Tags: php, recaptcha

Does anybody knows code for simple Recaptcha in PHP?

Say like adding two number that do random or some random values or strings etc. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). There's no point in reinventing the wheel, as the engineers at Google will probably do it better than you.

Security through obscurity will work in the short run, but your home-made captcha will probably be programatically cracked with OCR. reCAPTCHA "solvers" are actual people, so there's no way for you to make a foolproof captcha.